# Python comprehension: for x in [temp for temp in xlist if temp<=xmax]:

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
for x in [temp for temp in xlist if temp<=xmax]:
```

This code works, but looks like an unnecessarily foreign stuttering way of starting a for loop.

Is there a cleaner syntax?

Answer (score 4):

What are you trying to do here?

```
for x in xlist:
    if x > xmax: continue
```

will work.  (what does the rest of your for loop do?)  If it can be accomplished using only a list-comp, that may be the way to go.  If it can't, then you probably want the idiom above, or some variant that you'll see in the other answers posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in xlist:
    if x <= xmax:
        #do stuff
```

As an aside, if possible you'd want to use a generator expression in your original version, as that won't pre-create an unnecessary list.

```
for x in (temp for temp in xlist if temp <= xmax):
    #etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in filter(lambda x: x<=xmax, xlist):
    pass
# or with itertools (faster on python2, on py3 these are equivalent):
import itertools
for x in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x<=xmax, xlist):
    pass
```

But also look at [@mgilson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295830/1248008) which suggests that you may be able to rewrite the whole code as list comprehension.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `filter`?

```
filter(function, iterable)
```

`filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]`

In your case:

```
filter(lambda item: item <= xmax, xlist)
```

Comment: This is almost what what I was looking for. Thank you.